# create empty copy of another instance in symfony

Tags: symfony, copy, entity, instance, clone

Is it possible to copy an instance of an entity in symfony without its values ? 
For example i have the following Entity

```
class Dog{
private $_name;
__construct(){
$this->_name = null;
}
}
setName($name){
$this->_name = $name;
return $this;
}

getName(){
return $this->_name;
}

}

$billy = new Dog();
$billy->setName('billy')
```

Can i get copy "$billy" to get a new instance without the value "billy" for the name parameter ?

I know i can copy it and set a new Name or i can just create a new instance of it using new Dog() but is a method exist to do it this way ?

Comment: It's a weird requirement. You want a "copy" of an instance, but want to have it with a blank state. What's the difference with just creating a new instance?

Comment: Cause i don't know which entity to use. i'm using multiple entity from multiple namespace. I need to create a new instance  to create childrens of the one i've already hydrated. But i don't know exactly what is it's namespace. So because i don't want to use a lot of  condition to find the good entity i just want to copy the hydrated instance without its values.

Comment: No need to clone. You can simply do `$newDog = new $billy;`. `$newDog` will contain a brand new instance of `Dog`. See it [here](https://3v4l.org/3qFs9).

Comment: Oh i didn't know it was possible to do it ! that's perfect thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can overwrite magic PHP method `__clone` inside `Dog` entity to reset `$name` value

```
class Dog {
    private $name;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = null;
    }

    public function setName($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getName() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function __clone() {
        $this->name = null;
    }
}

$billy = new Dog();
$billy->setName('Billy');
$billy->getName(); // Returns 'Billy'

$clonedBilly = clone $billy;
$clonedBilly->getName(); // Returns null
```